# Programming an ATMEGA2560 using FTDI

Tags: arduino-mega, uploading, bootloader, ide, ftdi

I want to know how exactly do I program (upload arduino sketches) an ATMEGA2560 which is boot loaded with an Arduino Bootloader using a FTDI programmer and an Arduino IDE, is there any capacitors/resistors required?

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'FTDI Programmer' what you most likely mean is programming the ATMEGA2560 over the a serial protocol like RS232.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for my terminology. I have a FTDI breakout board [link](http://www.amazon.in/Breakout-Serial-L-type-Arduino-interfacing/dp/B00V626RKS?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=db671033-59a1-4318-815d-1fd17967dc37&kpid=B00V626RKS) which I want to use to upload arduino sketches to the atmega2560.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a bootloader, you just need to connect up four wires from the FTDI cable:

- Pin 1 (black) -> Ground
- Pin 2 (CTS)   -> not connected
- Pin 3 (Vcc)   -> 5V
- Pin 4 (TxD)   -> Rx (Mega pin D0)
- Pin 5 (RxD) -> Tx (Mega pin D1)
- Pin 6 (green) -> not connected

[image: FTDI connections]

This will not auto-reset, so you will have to press (and release) the Reset button on the board at the moment that the sketch starts to upload.

---

> How to make it auto reset?

What you *should* be able to do is connect RTS to Reset on the board, using a 0.1 µF capacitor (in series). I found in practice that this did not bring Reset low enough to trigger it - I'm not sure why, except maybe the board has a stronger pull-up resistor on /RESET than expected. That technique works for me on breadboard Arduinos.

Since it didn't work for me, I did not put it in my original answer. You could try that, and if it works, well and good.

Comment: I don't want to do that? How to make it auto reset?

Comment: See amended reply. Is there any reason why you don't just use the USB interface? That usually works.

Comment: I've fabricated a custom PCB with ATMEGA2560 mounted on it, I added your bootloader sketch and I'm trying to upload sketches to it using the arduino IDE, so that is why I'm using the FTDI chip to do this.